# JavaFx copy hyperlinks

Tags: java, javafx

I know it's possible to highlight and copy labels in JavaFx to the system clipboard, I'm wondering if the same can be done for hyperlinks. Does anyone have a solution to this? Open to all suggestions, thanks.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, see if you can create a `Context Menu` for the `HyperLink` that allows you to copy the link to the `Clipboard`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to handle this.

**Using a `ContextMenu`:**

```
ContextMenu copyMenu = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem copyLink = new MenuItem("Copy link...");
copyLink.setOnAction(event ->  {
    final Clipboard cb = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
    final ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
    content.putString(link.getText());
    cb.setContent(content);
});
```

**Using a `MouseEvent`:**

(this captures a middle-click on the link)

```
    link.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        if (event.getSource().equals(MouseButton.MIDDLE)) {
            final Clipboard cb = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
            final ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.putString(link.getText());
            cb.setContent(content);
        }
    });
```

As far as actually highlighting and selecting the link's text, that would require a lot more work than it's worth, in my opinion.

Comment: It's strange how you can't highlight a hyperlink in JavaFX, but your solution makes sense. If I decide to implement a highlight and selecting a link's test, I'll update my answer. Thanks!